# Is this Integral calculation correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Can someone confirm if my solution is right or if I have done something that is not permitted

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_\gamma e^{\pi z}=\int_\gamma \left( \frac{ e^{\pi z}}{\pi}\right)' \, dz \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{e^{\pi (3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1))}}{\pi}\right)' (3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1))' \,dz \\[8pt]
={} & \int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{e^{\pi (3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1))}}{\pi} (3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1))\right)'dz \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{\pi(3-3t^2 +i(t^3-3t+1))}}{\pi} (3-3t^2+i(t^3-3t+1))
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What exactly is your contour $\gamma$? Please write that out explicitly. In addition, the problem seems to be that when you parameterize your path, you don't actually integrate with respect to your parameterization variable $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(f(t)g(t))' \neq f'(t) g'(t)$ as you have written (moving from the first line to the second). Also, in moving from the second statement to the third, you have to change your variable of integration (but this could just be a typo rather than a lack of understanding)

Instead, write

$\int_\gamma e^{\pi z} \,dz = \int_{-1}^1 e^{\pi \gamma(t)} \gamma'(t) \, dt$

*then* use the chain-rule (i.e. $u$-substitution) to evaluate: let $s = \gamma(t)$, then $ds = \gamma'(t) dt$, and you have

$$
\int_{\gamma(-1)}^{\gamma(1)} e^{\pi s} \,ds = \left.\dfrac{1}{\pi} e^{\pi s} \right|_{s = \gamma(-1)}^{\gamma(1)}.
$$

Note that most of this can be bypassed by observing that $e^{\pi z}$ is analytic, so you can evaluate associated contour integrals by just taking the antiderivative ($\frac{1}{\pi} e^{\pi z}$) and evaluating at the endpoints of the contour (and in the special case the contour is closed, the result is zero).

Comment: I just realized how stupid what I posted was. Thank you for your detailed answer explaining to me what I should have done and not only pointing my mistake.

Comment: No problem. As long as you understand and learn from mistakes, you haven't done anything stupid.